# Ansible connect when there are multiple interactive prompts

Tags: ssh, ansible

I have an ansible inventory file with a single managed node.

When I try to connect via cli I get the following interactive prompt:

```
login as: 286
Keyboard-interactive authentication prompts from server:
| Password authentication
| Password:
```

Notice the extra line *Password authentication*
This is just information, you cannot actually input something here.

Trying to run an ssh connection test I run the following ad-hoc:

```
ansible --ask-pass all -i hosts -m win_ping
```

and get the error:

```
Server | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

I then run ssh with -v as an ssh_common_var and got the following line in between others:

> Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive\r\nPassword authentication\r\ndebug1: Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).\r\nAuthenticated to 108.16.126.45

I believe the extra message during interactive authentication causes some issues with the python library that uses it since ssh appears to authenticate to the controlled node.
Has anyone encountered anything similar to this?